# Check if file is a valid image

Tags: ruby

I'm using rmagick to manipulate image files. I use the ImageList.new on each file to get started. When I apply this method to an invalid image file I get the below error which interrupts the execution of the script:

RMagick.rb:1635:in `read': Improper image header (Magick::ImageMagickError)

Therefore I would like to be able to check whether a file is a valid image file before using this method.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the format of the image.  For example:

```
image = Magick::Image::read(file_path).first
image.format
```

So you can check if the format is one of the formats you expect:

```
image = Magick::Image::read(file_path).first
%w(JPEG GIF TIFF PNG).include? image.format
```

This is not based on the file name extension.  It giess you the actual format of the file.

Answer (score 3):

An exception seems like the perfect signal that an image is invalid... Why not simply rescue it?

If you really want to apply some other tests, you could use [FastImage](http://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) and request the type or size, for instance, and you will get `nil` if the header is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing images of a certain format(s), you could analyze their headers to determine if they are really valid images files.

For example, the first 3 bytes of a GIF file header are "GIF", according to this [GIF spec](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html) - so if you receive a file with a `.gif` extension, you could analyze it to verify its header matches the spec.

Comment: Yeah that works. I'm using this one-liner to check for PNG images:
File.new(filepath,"r").gets[0,4].include?("‰PNG")

If someone knows about a library I could use let me know.
THanks.

Answer (score 0):

install mimemagic gem

`gem 'mimemagic'`

open stream(bytes of target image)

```
url="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/rbIAAOSwojpgyQz1/s-l500.jpg"
result = URI.parse(url).open
```

then check data-stream's file type

for example:

`MimeMagic.by_magic(result).type == "image/jpeg"`

even though as mentioned above

`%w(JPEG GIF TIFF PNG).include?(MimeMagic.by_magic(result).type)`

this might be more elegant